# Problem with webserver on esp8266 that i want to return tvoc from SGP30 sensor

Tags: c++, arduino-esp8266

So i have this code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  
  if (mySensor.begin() == false) 
  {
    while (1);
  }
  sencon = true;

  mySensor.initAirQuality();
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(led, 0);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("");

  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  if (MDNS.begin("esp8266")) { Serial.println("MDNS responder started"); }
  
  server.on("/", []() {
    server.send(200, "text/plain", mySensor.TVOC());
  });
```

And i want to return tvoc from SGP30 sensor.
But i get:

```
expression cannot be used as a function
```

error when compiling. I tried converting it to string but it doesnt't worked for me. (idk if i made it wrong) I am using  WeMos D1 R1 board.
Full compiler output:

```
error: expression cannot be used as a function
   74 |     server.send(200, "text/plain", mySensor.TVOC());
      |                                                  ^
exit status 1
expression cannot be used as a function
```

I hope someone can help with this error beacuse i am c++ rookie.
Full code: https://pastebin.com/derki1df

Now i tried with:

```
server.send(200, "text/plain", mySensor.TVOC);
```

and it looks ok but now i get this error:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} to 'Stream*' [-fpermissive]
   74 |     server.send(200, "text/plain", mySensor.TVOC);
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
      |                                             |
      |                                             uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}
exit status 1
no matching function for call to 'send(int, const char [11], uint16_t&)'
```

Updated full code:
https://pastebin.com/90SJt7nk

Comment: `while (1);` causes undefined behavior by the way. Infinite loops that do not eventually perform IO/atomic/volatile/synchronization operations violate the forward-progress guarantee.

Comment: I added compiler output to question

Comment: Did you mean `mySensor.getTVOC()` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into the [github](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_SGP30_Arduino_Library/blob/33c7030330aff16372b9411493ab3bd4a8a72dd3/src/SparkFun_SGP30_Arduino_Library.h#L67) code to understand what public members that you can have from this library, there is no public function as such as `SGP30::TVOC()` but instead it's a member variable `SGP30::TVOC`. Even the traceback message is self-explanatory, telling you that `TVOC` is not a function expression.

So most probably your code should be:

```
#include <string>

/*... you code ...*/

#convert TVOC into string
server.send(200, "text/plain", std::to_string(mySensor.TVOC));
```

Comment: Now i get this error no matching function for call to 'send(int, const char [11], uint16_t&)'
So now can change this uint16 to something that i can pass to send function

Comment: Please update your question with your tries and posting traceback message.